# xcodebuild test with .xcarchive/.app/.ipa

Tags: xcode, testing, xcodebuild, ipa, xctool

I'd like to use xcodebuild to build an app with a command like:

`xcodebuild  -scheme my-app -workspace my-app.xcworkspace CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/tmp`

which will create a `my-app.app` in `/tmp/`. Then, further down my CI pipeline I would like to use this generated app to test:

`xcodebuild __some command to use my-app.app for testing__ test`.

Is this possible? I'm happy to use xcodebuild or xctool or any other tool to accomplish this.

Comment: Scarcely seems worthy of adding as an answer, but did you try this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_RUN_UNIT_TESTS_IN_OS_X_AND_IOS_FROM_THE_COMMAND_LINE_

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately I have tried that but it's not what I need. I'd like to have a build artifact that I can then pass into `xcodebuild`'s `test` action.